# C# Delegate use with Generic Method to return Task<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, delegates, task

I' m missing something here. I 'll be as clear as I can be.

let's say I have this method :

```
    public Task<CustomClass> TestMethod(string one, string two, int three)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

and I want to create a generic method that takes methods like these (through a delegate) and does something.

so let's say that I have this class with a delegate and a generic method:

```
public static class SomeClass
{
    public delegate T CallbackMethodDelegate<T>(params object[] args);
    public static void InvokeMethod<T>(CallbackMethodDelegate<Task<T>> method, params object[] args) where T: class
        {
            method.Invoke(args);
        }

}
```

my understanding says that T can be a class, so I should be able to do this somewhere in the code :

```
    SomeClass.InvokeMethod<CustomClass>(TestMethod, "one", "two", 3);
```

But I get compile error

```
CS1503:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'SomeClass.CallBackMethodDelegate<Task<CustomClass>>'
```

I thought it might be an async thing but even if I change the delegate to void I get the same error. Any ideas what I'm missing? Seems like I'm misunderstanding something important about delegates or generics here. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please, add the error message.

Comment: CS1503:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'SomeClass.CallBackMethodDelegate<Task<CustomClass>>'

Comment: `TestMethod` doesn't take a single parameter of `object[]` so you can't use it like that.

Comment: @DavidG you 're right, completely misunderstood the params keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error suggests your method is not compatible with the delegate. The delegate requires `object[]` as a parameter your method has 3 explicit parameters `string,string,int` this is not compatible.

what you can do if you really need this is you can create a set of invoke methods that cover wide range of methods:

```
void InvokeMethod<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> method, TParam1 param1)
void InvokeMethod<TParam1, TResult>(Func<TParam1,Task<TResult>> method, TParam1 param1)
void InvokeMethod<TParam1,TParam2, TResult>(Func<TParam1, TParam2 ,Task<TResult>> method, TParam1 param1, TParam2 param2)
```

and so on as many parameters you need to have.

you can reduce those methods to single implementation that is not type safe but not accessible directly

```
void InvokeMethodImpl(Delegate method, params object[] args)
   => method.DynamicInvoke(args);
```

so all generic methods would just call this method:

```
 void InvokeMethod<TParam1, TResult>(Func<TParam1,Task<TResult>> method, TParam1 param1) 
      => InvokeMethodImpl(method, param1);
```

Comment: That's really smart. That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you, I was stuck!